# Find files with applescript

Tags: applescript

I am attempting to create an application that will find a file and Append it based on user input but i am having issues with the finding part.

```
display dialog "Please Enter Password" default answer "Enter Password Here"
set pass to text returned of result
display dialog "Please Enter file to be located. Use *'s for parts unknown" default answer "File Name Here"
set fle to text returned of result
do shell script "find / -name '$fle'" password pass with administrator privileges
```

thats the segment of code for that portion but no matter how i modify it i keep getting this

```
error "find: /dev/fd/9: Bad file descriptor
find: /dev/fd/11: Not a directory
find: /dev/fd/12: Not a directory" number 1
```

the actual input i was giving for variable"fle" was Gameover* ; nothing to do with /dev/fd/(random number)

Answer (score 0):

Although it will take forever, try:

```
display dialog "Please Enter Password" default answer "Enter Password Here"
set pass to text returned of result
display dialog "Please Enter file to be located. Use *'s for parts unknown" default answer "File Name Here"
set fle to text returned of result
set myResults to (do shell script "find / -name " & quoted form of fle & ";" password pass with administrator privileges)
```

You may be better off using mdfind.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you adayzdone! The final and working script is this in case any one else ever needs it.

```
display dialog "Please Enter Password" default answer "Enter Password Here"
set pass to text returned of result
display dialog "Please enter file to be located. Use *'s for parts unknown" default answer "File Name Here"
set fle to text returned of result
display dialog "Please enter where you would like to look. Leave default answer if unsure." default answer "/"
set loc to text returned of result
set newfile to (do shell script "find " & quoted form of loc & " -name " & quoted form of fle password pass with administrator privileges)
display dialog newfile
```